# To group my observation into unequal bin size in R

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I am new to R programming Language and thus facing a little difficulty. I have a data frame where I want to group data on their market capitalization, for each month.

```
Year <- c(2000:2010)
```

and for each year there are 100 stocks with their ME values.
I want to have a SizeGrp column which groups the stocks into top 30% middle 40% and bottom 30% as group 1,2 and 3 respectively, for each year.

```
data <- data %>% 
          group_by(year) %>% 
          mutate(SizeGrp = ntile(ME,3)) %>% 
          ungroup()
```

I have tried this but it divides into 33% each.

Answer (score 1):

You could use quantiles to identify the bottom 30% and top 30% assigning to SizeGrp 1 & 3 respectively then assign the remainder to SizeGrp 2

```
data <- data %>% group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(SizeGrp = case_when(ME < quantile(ME, c(0.3,0.7))[1] ~ 1L,
                             ME > quantile(ME, c(0.3,0.7))[2] ~ 3L,
                             TRUE ~ 2L))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try the fonction ***quantcut***:

```
data <- data %>% 
      group_by(year) %>% 
      mutate(SizeGrp = quantcut(x, q=c(0.3,0.7,1.0), na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
      ungroup()
```